# Addition of two simple periodic waves using Complex Sinusoidal forms. Not making logical sense.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

This will be a tad long post, so I do apologise for the general reader, but I don't see any other way to ask my problem without visually showing you what doesn't make sense.

Using this neat website: [Desmos Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)

We can play around with graphing of functions, etc...

So we can all agree that if you take two simple cos functions of the same nature they should be exactly the same, but the amplitude twice as much.

$$cos(x) + cos(x) = 2cos(x)$$

Great so we have this fundamental logical reasoning to fall back on, but now let's make it more interesting. Let's take two cos functions with each their own phase, but same amplitude and add them together using algebraic expressions..

$$ cos(x+ \phi) + cos(x+ \psi) = ? $$

We can derive a general expression using Euler’s identity $e^{j \theta}=cos\theta + jsin\theta$

Once we derive our expression. If we both set $\psi=\phi=0$ Then it would be the same as our initial $cos(x)+cos(x)=2cos(x)$ Following along my deriving path on the images provided:

You see that the final expression comes out to:

$$
 \sqrt{2 + cos(\psi-\phi)}cos(x+arctan(\frac{sin\phi + sin\psi}{cos\phi + cos\phi})
$$

Which is all well and dandy until you come to our original question.. Setting both $\phi=\psi=0$ Should get us $2cos(x)$, but instead it gives us $\sqrt{3}cos(x)$

Just a little below what we would expect of adding the two..

Can someone either point out a mistake in my math or is this how its supposed to be?

[image: Page 1]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a factor 2 missing in the product term when you are working out the square of $(\cos\phi+\cos\psi),$ and again with the sines.

Comment: oms you are right...